# Change a division width based on screen resolution

Tags: html, css, width, division, window-resize

I want to change a division width based on screen resolution like bootstrap column col-md-6 col-xs-8.

But I want to give a different percentage for different resolution, for example 20% width for medium size and 90% for small size, that s why I do not use the bootstrap.

I ve searched for an answer, but I didn't find.

Comment: Did you try using Media Queries http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work. ***You don't have to use Bootstrap but Media queries are entirely customisable.***

Comment: I m not looking for code, just want to learn how to solve. That's why I don't need write what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `media queries`. For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    body {
        width: 70%;
    }
}
```

> Here is a solid list of media queries: [Comprehensive Media Query
>   List](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)